# how to check for a macro defined in a c file in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a `#define ONB` in a c file which (with several `#ifndef...#endif`s) changes many aspects of a programs behavior. Now I want to change the project makefile (or even better Makefile.am) so that if ONB is defined and some other options are set accordingly, it runs some special commands.

I searched the web but all i found was checking for environment variables... So is there a way to do this? Or I must change the c code to check for that in environment variables?(I prefer not changing the code because it is a really big project and i do not know everything about it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Questions:** My level is insufficient to ask in comments so I will have to ask here:

- How and when is the define added to the target in the first place?
- Do you essentially want a way to be able to post compile query the binaries to to determine if a particular define was used?
- It would be helpful if you could give a concrete example, i.e. what are the special commands you want run, and what are the .c .h files involved?

**Possible solution:** Depending on what you need you could use LLVM tools to maybe generate and examine the AST of your code to see if a define is used.  But this seems a little like over engineering.

**Possible solution:** You could also use `#includes` to pull in .c or header files and a conditional error be generated, or compile (to a .o), then if the compile fails you know it is defined or not.  But this has it's own issues depending on how things are set-up in your make file.

Comment: i don't want to query binaries... i want to change makefile based on a define in a abc.h file if possible. based on your solutoin can i include a '.h' file in a Makefile and use #ifeq on what i defined?

Comment: Say you have file you want to check for having a define, e.g. main.cpp

Comment: You create procedurally or otherwise a `test_define.cpp` which includes it with a `#ifdef SOME_DEFINE ... #error .... #endif` You then need in the `Makefile` a `TEST_DEFINE=$(shell cc test_define.cpp -o test_define && echo FOUND)`.  Then you can use a #if within the makefile on TEST_DEFINE.

Comment: I haven't test all that.  So possibly some errors in my logic / code.  But I think the basic idea is sound.  I have seen it used to test for functionality of headers and stuff.  But its a bit of a hack.

Comment: I will test + write up a full answer if that sounds good enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47764/discussion-between-voltaire-and-mhk).